# NHibernate fetch including children and a criteria

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, nhibernate

Being relative new to NHibernate I have inherited some basic coding which I have to modify. I have a bunch of objects of type Group. Each group can have one or more children of type Group and again the children can have children of type Group and so on. Each Group object has a property/field called Deleted with the value "deletedgroup" (a kind of soft deletion). In case a group has the Deleted field set to "deletedgroup" is should not be selected and so should the children and grand children. In other words I need to get a list of all groups not having the deleted field set to "deletedgroup".
I have this piece of code inherited but it doesn't include a criteria for the deleted field which is new, i.e. the code retrieves all groups.
How do I expand the code to fulfil my request. I have tried with .Where and .Criteria but I get either compile errors og the restriction doesn't work.

Enherited code (selects all groups):

```
var allGroups = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IUnitOfWork>().Session
                        .QueryOver<Group>()
                        .Fetch(g => g.ChildGroups).Eager
                        .Fetch(g => g.Vacancies).Eager
                        .TransformUsing(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer())
                        .List();
```

Answer (score 0):

I typically favour `LINQ` queries with NH as I find the syntax more intuitive. The LINQ provider in NH is not perfect, there are times when `QueryOver` is far superior. However, in this case I think this `LINQ`-based query should work for you:

```
var activeGroupIds = 
    ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IUnitOfWork>().Session
        .Query<Group>()
        .Where(g => g.Deleted != "deletedgroup")
        .Select(g => g.Id);

var allGroups = 
    ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IUnitOfWork>().Session
        .Query<Group>()
        .FetchMany(g => g.ChildGroups)
        .FetchMany(g => g.Vacancies)
        .Where(g => activeGroupIds.Contains(g.Id))
        .ToList();
```

Maybe try this and see if it has the desired effect.

Comment: Didn't work. Seems like the where-clause filters out every group so the result is zero groups just as I have experienced using the orignal query with a where-clause.
Omitting the where-clause returns all groups as the original query.

Comment: Ah. So do you need something like a correlated sub-query that first finds eligible groups with the `Deleted != "deletedgroup"` and then only returns groups that are in that list?

Comment: I've edited my answer with this concept but I'm not sure it's exactly what you're looking for.